# Multiprocessing how do I improve this?

Tags: python, operating-system, multiprocessing

I have a script in which I am taking xlsx files and reformatting them and creating a txt document recording the reformatting. The script works well and does what I want it to do. However, It is not as fast as I would like as the multiprocessing is not being fully utilized. At times there may only be a handful of files being reformatted in each "files_xlsx". If I remove the processes.join() it ends up crashing. Ideally, I would like it to work on as many xlsx sheets at a time from multiple "files_xlsx"/directories etc. But I have had no luck in writing my code to do so. Is there an easy alternative to adjust my current code to allow it to work on more xlsx at a time?

Comment: `for file in files_xlsx:` creates a single iterable for you to work from. You need to raise the multiprocessing up.

Comment: You should limit the amount of processes to your available cores, otherwise performance will drop.

Comment: How do I do that Jim?

Answer (score 1):

The most straighforward way to take advantage of Python's `multiprocessing` library is to use `Pool`.

Please review the modifications to your code as seen below. Note that I did not modify `def rename_sheets` in any way.

```
# From Python 3.4 onwards, you can use pathlib
from pathlib import Path

def convert_excel_txt(fil): 
# directories is a globally defined variable. Not needed as an argument
# Variable name *file* is not a good idea. 

# This method is to process one and only one file
# The multiprocessing is taken care of by Pool
    open_xl = openpyxl.load_workbook(fil)
    titles = xls.sheet_names()
    # print(len(titles))
    count = 1
    for title in titles:
        # print("{}.| {}".format(count, title))
        sheet_title_value = rename_sheets(title, count, open_xl, fil)
        # We'll navigate to the directory we're working on
        directory = Path(fil).parent
        with open(directory+"\\Reference_Sheets\\"+fil[:-5]+".txt", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
                outfile.write('\n'+str(count)+". "+sheet_title_value)
                count +=1


directories = open(r"C:\Python38\Projects\s_&p_500_links_test.txt", "r")

files = []

for directory in directories:
    directory = directory[:-1]
    print(directory)
    report_type = "Annual"
    path = os.chdir(directory)
    files = os.listdir(directory+"\\"+report_type)
    print(files)

files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']
pool = Pool(24)
pool.map(convert_excel_txt, files_xlsx )
```

To time the execution of various versions of the code, proceed as follows:

```
import time
import datetime

overall_start_time = time.time()
print('Started at ', time.strftime('%X %x %Z'))

# timed code goes here

print ("Time elapsed overall (hours:min:sec): %s" % str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=(time.time()- overall_start_time))))
```

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html): https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: should you use the max cores? I believe I have 16. and the function name is mp

Comment: Start with your core count. If that works well, increase it slightly, to say 24, proceed until it starts to slow down as you increase the pool number. It's more of an art than a science to find the optimal number.

Comment: Ok cheers I got the following error TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' pool.map(mp, files_xlsx, s_route) which is a string e.g "D:\Data\US\Sec Interactive\test\test\Connectone Bancorp Inc CIK 1462694" 

Can I also check, is your code purposely indented like that? or should the files pool etc be part of the loop?

Comment: The nesting is purposeful. As for your question about the call to your method, I think it's best if you post that method in your original question, so I can understand how it works.

Comment: I added the full script above, it's probably incredibly messy and ineficient but im pretty new to coding;.

Comment: thanks for the help so far unfortunately it came up with this error :No such file or directory: '10-K 2012-03-09.xlsx' pool.map(convert_excel_txt, files_xlsx) I would usually do a loop to change the files xlsx to the directory + it something like xlsx_path+"\\"+file but i would imagine that would cause a bottle kneck again?

Comment: as in for f in files_xlsx:
xlsx_path = directory+"\\"+report_type+"\\"+f

Comment: The fundamental problem you had originally was applying multiprocessing at the wrong level. I'm trying to be specific enough to help, but I see now that my point is lost in too much detail. The `directories` list should contain all the files fully qualified. Your current, I presume, arises when saving the converted file.

Comment: I get what you are saying - I need to rewrite the code so that it can iterate through multiple files rather than a directory at a time which is what I am doing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: On the assumption that you're working in Python 3.4 or later, you can use the `pathlib` directory to derive `directory` as follows `directory = Path(fil).parent`. I have updated my answer with details.

Comment: I would appreciate at least an upvote, if you don't feel that you can accept the answer. I am trying to increase my reputation score and every point counts!

Comment: I have been thinking of an alternative solution using a dictionary I will check out your changes in a bit and have upvoted you

Comment: I think i have managed to fix it although not 100% sure I was wondering if you know how I can time it? I use powershell so I need to add a time script. I usually use time and then do a start - end calculation. But here it just says 0 which I understand why I just dont know how you would account for this

Comment: I have added code to time the execution at the bottom of my answer.